# Allow controller action in symfony access cotrol

Tags: php, api, symfony, controller, fosrestbundle

I have an API project in Symfony. Authentication is secured by the JWT token. I want to allow 2 actions in the controller which can be used without login users.

- /point/{param}/elmeter
- /point/{param}/measurement

I tried to allow in `security.yaml` access control without success.

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/point/.*/(elmeter|measurement)$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

```php
    /**
     * @param string $sign
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @Route("/point/{sign}/elmeter", methods={"POST"}
     */
    public function postPointElmeterAction(string $sign, Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }

   /**
     * @param string $sign
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @Route("/point/{sign}/measurement", methods={"POST"}, name="api_point_measurement")
     */
    public function postPointMeasurementAction(string $sign, Request $request)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: Which library you are using for  JWT authentication?

Comment: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle but this works fine. When I call actions with token in request then i get response. But I want call actions without auth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify this route in firewalls section in `security.yaml` like this:

```
security:
    ...
    ...
    firewalls
        point:
            pattern: ^/api/point/.*/(elmeter|measurement)$
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/point/.*/(elmeter|measurement)$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```